# Firebase hosting deployment error Error: Error: 404, Requested entity was not found

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, firebase-hosting

i have hosted a static website on firebase and i am using node.js.
when i am trying to deploy my website i am facing this error.

```
 C:\Users\Ankur-PC\Desktop>firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'wo*****win'...

i  deploying hosting

**Error: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found.**
```

i was also  trying these cmd to resolve this error

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the source of your website is in C:\Users\Ankur-PC\Desktop , you are executing the command in the wrong directory

try to cd [source dir] and then deploy

Answer (score 51):

I had to add `site` property to `firebase.json` to fix this.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "my-app-id",
    "public": "app",
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes, that did work, thank you so much!

Comment: It absolutely worked!

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure that you have a Web app added in your Firebase console.

[image]

Then, go to Build -> Hosting and set that up. You'll be prompted to add a name for your site. Copy what you type in the box here...

[image]

...and add it to your firebase.json file here:

```
"hosting": {
"site": "stack-overflow-example", // here
"public": "build/web",
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
}
```

Comment: If you have followed the documentation and still have this issue, then this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

**update your Firebase npm package to latest version . It works for me**

npm install -g firebase-tools

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error due to an incorrectly configured `.firebaserc` file. I had mixed up the name of my project with the name of the hosting target. A correctly configured file would look something like this:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "dev-project",
    "dev": "dev-project",
    "prod": "prod-project"
  },
  "targets": {
    "prod-project": {
      "hosting": {
        "app-one": [
          "prod-project-hosting-target-for-app-one"
        ],
        "app-two": [
          "prod-project-hosting-target-for-app-two"
        ]
      }
    },
    "dev-project": {
      "hosting": {
        "app-one": [
          "dev-project-hosting-target-for-app-one"
        ],
        "app-two": [
          "dev-project-hosting-target-for-app-two"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and finally solved it.

**1. firebase login
2. firebase use --add (Choose the right Project ID)
3. firebase init (select hosting, than correct Project ID)
4. if needed (npm run build)
5. firebase deploy**

Solution was number 2
Choosing the right Project ID
Because some how firebase commands was refering automatically to a wrong Project ID

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have a redirect to a Cloud Run or Cloud Function, make sure it's running.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I initiate the project in CLI, and THEN setup a second hosting in the same project.

The solution is to edit the firebase.json and adding the new hosting you wish to deploy:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "web-page", // <-- This is a nickname of a resource (a hosting in firebase)
      "public": "public",
      ....
    },
    {
      "target": "web-app",
      "public": "public",
      ....
    },

  ]
}
```

Now you have to select the target:

```
firebase target:apply hosting [name] [resource]
```

For example, let's say the name is "web-page" as in the .json and the name of the hosting you are targeting is "hosting-web", this last one is literally the name you use in Firebase Console:

```
firebase target:apply hosting web-page hosting-web
```

For more reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I tried to have main domain and subdomin.

The problem was this message  `404, Requested entity was not found`
because I tried to deploy my subdomain to the hosting server and the `resource_id` entity does not exist in the file of `.firebasesrc` I added in the `targets` filed the same ID of the firebase hosting project ID and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every above solution but it didn,t work.
This is how i solve it.

1. Delete firebase files and dist folder {firebaserc, firebase.jason, dist}
2. Now build again and follow all steps

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't accept `groups` name with white spaces. e.g:- iOS

[image]

iOS SIT Tester always get failed on

> Error: failed to distribute to testers/groups: HTTP Error: 404,
> Requested entity was not found.

*wheres JinglePayTesters succeed without any problem.*

```
    # Deploy on Firebase 
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: "Upload to firebase app distribution"
    inputs:
      targetType: "inline"
      script: |
          npm i -g firebase-tools
          ls -la $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/output/
          firebase appdistribution:distribute  *.ipa \
            --app "$(app_id)" \
            --token "$(firebasetoken)" \
            --groups "JinglePayTesters" \
            --release-notes "From Azure Devops" \
            --debug \
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/output/'
```